# Overriding registration page

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-7, user-registration

I'm using drupal v7, and I wanted to override the registration form.

The custom form will be a client-side 3 steps registration, using jQueryUI.accordion.

Solution with a new module:

```
reg.module: [X_form_user_login_alter(); X_form_user_login_block_alter();]

reg.tpl.php: [Html/JavaScript/CSS]

template.php: [X_preprocess_user_register() { $variables['rendered'] = drupal_render($variables['form']); }]
```

The solution is well displayed, & all resources are available in the page.

The issue is, that any button in the form html(reg.tpl.php), is not calling the jQuery click event, and instead it preforms submit to the server.

How can I prevent the submit?

Is there a way to use client-side code in drupal?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the scripts are included in the page.

And in jQuery, you can use:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

to prevent form submission.

Comment: Thank you. I have the js files linked. after adding 'preventDefault' I still get submitted. The jquery isn't called (alert(...)) at all.